# NMinimize keeps returning Indeterminate for well defined function

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, numerics, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

I am attempting to numerically optimize a function of only 2 parameters `k, \[Theta]`.

The function is well-defined and the constraints are simple. However, the optimisation keeps returning `Indeterminate` or `not a real number` comment over the parameter space, i.e. `function value not a real number at {k,\[Theta]} = {0.918621,0.716689}`.

If I instead initialize {k,[Theta]} to these values and run the function, it does provide a value. I am unsure why the optimization fails. The *MWE* is provided below. Some things I have noticed is that the function value `val` can return some really small imaginary components that should be zero. If I force the value to be real via either `Chop` or `Re`, I keep getting an `Indeterminate` value.

How can I get around this?

**MWE:**

```
s[0 | 0.] = 0;
s[x_] = x Log2[x];
SetAttributes[s, Listable]

A = {{0.0632, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.3065, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.0632, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.3065}};
B = {{0.3065, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.0632, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3065, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.0632}};
T = {{2 k Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + k + 1, 0, 0, 6 k Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - k - 1}, {0, 2 k Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + 3 - 3 k, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 k Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + 3 - 3 k, 0}, {6 k Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - k - 1, 0, 0, 2 k Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + k + 1}};

C1 = A.T.A;
C2 = A.T.B;
C3 = B.T.A;
C4 = B.T.B;
C5 = KroneckerProduct[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, C1] + KroneckerProduct[{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, C2] + KroneckerProduct[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, C3] + KroneckerProduct[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, C4];

val = Total[s[Eigenvalues[C5]]] - Total[s[Eigenvalues[C1]]]  - Total[s[Eigenvalues[C4]]];
```

I then try to optimize `val` using:

```
NMinimize[{val, 0<=k<=1, 0<\[Theta]<=2\[Pi]}, {k, \[Theta]}]
```

which does not work. Even `val /. {k->0.5, \[Theta]->0.1}` fails. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem.** OP constructs a symmetric matrix `C5` of size $8 \times 8$ that in theory has rank $4$. Therefore four eigenvalues are exactly zero in theory, but not in floating point arithmetic. Here is a simple example to illustrate:

```
SeedRandom[1];
M=RandomReal[{-1,1},{4,8}];
Eigenvalues[Transpose[M].M] (* 8x8 matrix that in theory has rank 4)
(* 
  {4.29967,
   3.09331,
   1.37365,
   0.280941,
   3.84658*10^-16,
   -1.84698*10^-16,
   -6.69403*10^-17,
   -6.00174*10^-17} *)
```

Instead of four zero eigenvalues, we get four eigenvalues close to $0$ including slightly negative ones. Therefore, complex values are obtained when OP's function `s[...]` is applied. One approach is to use the fact that the nonzero eigenvalues of $M^TM$ are the eigenvalues of $MM^T$:

```
Eigenvalues[M.Transpose[M]]
(* {4.29967,
    3.09331,
    1.37365,
    0.280941} *)
```

This yields directly the four eigenvalues of interest.

**Solution.** A modification of OP's code in this spirit is (please restart Mathematica before using this to avoid conflicts with previous definitions):

```
s[x_]:=Total[x*Log2[x]];

A=DiagonalMatrix[{0.0632,0.3065,0.0632,0.3065}];
B=DiagonalMatrix[{0.3065,0.0632,0.3065,0.0632}];
AB=MatrixPower[A.A+B.B,1/2];

f[k_?NumericQ,θ_?NumericQ]:=With[{T={
   {2 k Cos[θ]^2+k+1,0,0,6 k Cos[θ]^2-k-1},
   {0,2 k Sin[θ]^2+3-3 k,0,0},
   {0,0,2 k Sin[θ]^2+3-3 k,0},
   {6 k Cos[θ]^2-k-1,0,0,2 k Cos[θ]^2+k+1}}},
      s[Eigenvalues[AB.T.AB]]-s[Eigenvalues[A.T.A]]-s[Eigenvalues[B.T.B]]
];
```

Using `NMinimize` yields a point where `6 k Cos[θ]^2-k-1` vanishes, that is, where $T$ is diagonal. I am guessing (without having analyzed in detail) that all points on that curve are minima, as indicated in this plot:

```
Show[{
   Plot3D[f[k,θ],{k,0,1},{θ,0,Pi},AxesLabel->{"k","θ"}],
   ParametricPlot3D[{1/(-1+6 Cos[θ]^2),θ,f[1/(-1+6 Cos[θ]^2),θ]},
                     {θ,0,Pi},PlotStyle->{Thick,Green}]
}]
```

[image]

The value along this curve is

```
With[{a=0.0632,b=0.3065},
  8/Log[2]* ((a^2+b^2) Log[a^2+b^2]-a^2 Log[a^2]-b^2 Log[b^2])
]
(* 0.192641 *)
```

**Explanation for `Eigenvalues[AB.T.AB]` ignoring details:** OP's matrix `C5` can be defined as follows:

```
X = ArrayFlatten[{{A,B}}];
C5 = Transpose[X].T.X;
```

Let `S` be a matrix square root of `T`, where `S` is also symmetric. Then equivalently `C5 = Transpose[X].S.S.X`. Denoting `M = S.X` this gives `C5 = Transpose[M].M`. By the example at the beginning of this answer, the nonzero eigenvalues of `C5` are equal to the eigenvalues of `M.Transpose[M] = S.X.Transpose[X].S = S.(A.A+B.B).S = S.AB.AB.S` and they are equal (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices)) to the eigenvalues of `AB.S.S.AB = AB.T.AB`.

Comment: This gives a good indication of what is causing the issue. However, I'm not sure I follow why `C5` in the OP is equivalent to `AB.T.AB` with `AB` defined in this answer.

Comment: They are not equal as matrices, but the nonzero eigenvalues are equal, see the edit. The numerical advantage is that `AB.T.AB` has size $4\times 4$, like in the example at the beginning.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276974/equality-contraint-violated-with-nminimize, in case you are able to look at it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

s[0 | 0.] = 0;
s[x_] = x Log2[x];
SetAttributes[s, Listable]
```

Use exact values for `A` and`B`

```
A = {{0.0632, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.3065, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.0632, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0.3065}} // Rationalize;
B = {{0.3065, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.0632, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.3065, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0.0632}} // Rationalize;
T = {{2 k Cos[θ]^2 + k + 1, 0, 0, 6 k Cos[θ]^2 - k - 1}, {0, 
    2 k Sin[θ]^2 + 3 - 3 k, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    2 k Sin[θ]^2 + 3 - 3 k, 0}, {6 k Cos[θ]^2 - k - 1, 0, 0, 
    2 k Cos[θ]^2 + k + 1}};

C1 = A . T . A;
C2 = A . T . B;
C3 = B . T . A;
C4 = B . T . B;
C5 = KroneckerProduct[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, C1] + 
   KroneckerProduct[{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, C2] + 
   KroneckerProduct[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, C3] + 
   KroneckerProduct[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, C4];

val = Total[s[Eigenvalues[C5]]] - Total[s[Eigenvalues[C1]]] - 
   Total[s[Eigenvalues[C4]]];

{min, arg} = 
 NMinimize[{val, 0 <= k <= 1, 0 < θ <= 2 π}, {k, θ}]

(* {0.192641, {k -> 0.218967, θ -> 3.41361}} *)
```